# Is it an ok practice to keep pointers dereferenced?

Tags: c++, data, memory

For me, I prefer having all my variables, not as pointers. Is it ok to keep all heap-allocated variables dereferenced?

For example:

```
#include "Foo.hpp"
#include "Bar.hpp"

class Foo {
private:
 Bar* ptr = new Bar();
};
```

Would it be ok to have Bar as a dereferenced pointer, without causing **any** issues?

Example:

```
Bar b = *(new Bar());
```

Comment: sure it's fine, but `b` is a copy and the `new Bar` object is leaked. Never use naked new. Either use plain values (here: `Bar b;` or `Bar b = Bar()`) or use smart pointers (e.g. `Bar b = *std::make_unique<Bar>()`)

Comment: What advantages do you see with this approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> For me, I prefer having all my variables, not as pointers.

That's a good goal. If you are able to use C++11 or higher, that should be achievable for almost all use cases. The containers from the standard library and smart pointers make that possible. There will be exceptions but they should be rare.

> Is it ok to keep all heap-allocated variables dereferenced?

From your posted code, it appears as though you want to use:

```
class Foo {
  private:
    Bar b = *(new Bar());
};
```

While that is synactically valid, it is wrong from a software standpoint. That line leaks memory. You are better off using the much simpler form:

```
class Foo {
  private:
    Bar b;
};
```

If you need to initialize `b` using something other than the default constructor, you may use

```
class Foo {
  private:
    Bar b = B(...); // Fill in the arguments for B's constructor
};
```

or even

```
class Foo {
  private:
    Bar b = someFunctionThatReturnsB(...); // Fill in the arguments for the function
};
```

Comment: So `class Foo {
  private:
    Bar b;
};`
would be allocated on the heap?

Comment: If you allocate a `Foo` from the heap, then the `b` object of the `Foo` will also be allocated on the heap. If `Foo` is on the stack, then the `b` will also be on the stack.

Answer (score 6):

You really need to learn the language. The first example doesn't compile. The second example, if Bar b is declared in a context where it compiles, allocates and constructs an object on the heap, then uses assignment to assign a copy in a local variable, and leaks the object on the heap.

You are not "keeping a pointer dereferenced", you are making a copy of the object that the pointer points to.

Comment: "The first example doesn't compile" It does: https://godbolt.org/z/PQyTIg

Answer (score 2):

> Is it ok to keep all heap-allocated variables dereferenced?

There is no such thing as "heap-allocated variables". There are objects with dynamic storage duration (a.k.a. "heap-allocated"), but they are not associated with **a name**.

You can *initialise* an automatic storage duration (a.k.a. "stack-allocated variable") *pointer object*, from the result of a `new` expression, that *points to* the dynamic object. The **pointer** is the variable.

> Would it be ok to have `Bar` as a dereferenced pointer, without causing any issues?
>
> E.g. `Bar b = *(new Bar());`

No, that's not ok. It doesn't do what you think it does, it leaks an object and is a gratuitious use of `new`.

Much better is

```
Bar b;
```